# What causes the error 'Not Found SoftDeletingTrait Class'?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I just updated from Laravel 4.1 to 4.2.7. I am trying to delete with Soft Delete using:

```
use SoftDeletingTrait;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

But this gives the error 'Not Found SoftDeletingTrait Class'. What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just call this by type **'use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;'**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class User extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

=> OR <=

Go to config/app.php & add Alias

**For laravel 4**

```
'SoftDeletingTrait'     => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait',
```

**For Laravel 5**

```
'SoftDeletes' => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes::class';

or use on model or controller file

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

Answer (score 7):

if you are using laravel 5.1 you have to use the following,

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;`

not

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;`

Answer (score 4):

Remove:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
use SoftDeletingTrait;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Add:

```
protected $softDelete = true;
```

Comment: Laravel should update [their soft-delete documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting), thanks! :)

Comment: This answer applies if you are on Laravel 4.1, but the OP stated they just upgraded to 4.2. The Laravel documentation correctly differentiates these options in versions [4.1](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/eloquent#soft-deleting) and [4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting).

Comment: Actually, this was the solution on Laravel 5.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your Model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Hrshadhin\Userstamps\UserstampsTrait;
```